# Eclipse call hierarchy not working on interface implementation

Tags: java, eclipse

When the code instantiates class as the type of it's interface the class implements and calls the interface method, the method call isn't shown in the call hierarchy of the method implementation (concrete class).

Is this intentional, a bug or a matter of configuration?

Answer (score 0):

> ...the method call isn't shown in the call hierarchy of the method
>   implementation (concrete class).

That's because the concrete class might not be known until run-time.

Here is an example of where the concrete class is known when **add()** is called; it can't possibly be anything but **ArrayList**:

```
final Collection<Integer> coll = new ArrayList<Integer>();
coll.add(3);
```

In that example Eclipse could (but does not) show **ArrayList** in the call hierarchy for **add()**; instead it shows **Collection**.

But what about this example?..

```
int rand = new Random().nextInt(99);
Collection<Integer> coll2 = (rand < 50) ? new ArrayList<Integer>() : new ArrayDeque<Integer>();
coll2.add(5);
```

In  this case when Eclipse shows the call hierarchy for **add()** it can't know whether the concrete class is **ArrayList** or **ArrayDeque**, but either way it knows for sure that the interface type is **Collection** so that is what is shown in the call hierarchy.

> Is this intentional, a bug or a matter of configuration?

Well you'd have to ask the Eclipse Team for the final word on that, but in my opinion it's intentional and working correctly.

It's certainly not a bug, and as far as I know you can't change the configuration to replace the interface type with the concrete class if it is known with certainty at compile time. (That might be possible I suppose, but not a good idea IMO; it would only serve to confuse.)